# Qt SDK and CD/DVD burning

Tags: c++, qt, qt4

Does Qt SDK provides some  facilities for CD/DVD burning.
More specific , if yes please give some class reference.
Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, Qt doesn't include any CD or DVD burning API.  You'll need to find another software package to do that (of course you are still free to use Qt for the GUI parts)

Answer (score 3):

Qt has nothing to do with CD/DVD burning. Its a GUI toolkit. it also have general purpose structures.

for CD/DVD burning you need to use other tools like [`wodim`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cdrkit)

Answer (score 1):

Its also a good idea to see what others are doing at qt-apps.For instance i found this application http://qt-apps.org/content/show.php/Silicon?content=149696

You can download it and look at the source.